# How to get this electric panel up to code?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

This is my situation.  Am going to list my house, but this panel has always been like this.  We covered it with a mirror the whole time we’ve lived here.  I know, I know.  NOT the smartest move I’m sure.  Question is, will it meet code requirements if I have a cover or door installed?  Or is something more extensive needed?
[image]

[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: You need to purchase a dead face cover for it   Once the breakers are covered and lead in place a standard cover may be with the dead face or put the mirror back up on a hinge , similar has worked for me.

Comment: Can you get us photos of any labeling that might be on the inside left or inside right of this panel, as well as a photo of the label on the back below the breakers?

Comment: Code requirements may be function fo your location.

Comment: Oh dear, Mr. Snippy has been busy... You're in luck, we have a true panel expert on here, but will need those label photos. Also, what are the *exact* dimensions of the gray box?  That may help identify options...

Comment: @EdBeal  Almost perfect answer. But I think the OP will need to trace down and label the circuits. Panel looks professionally wired, nice and neat. So just needs labeling.

Comment: Yeah, we're going to need to identify the panel model to know *which* dead face cover, specifically, you need.  Clear pictures of any labels (including the ones on the breakers) will likely be helpful, as well as a picture of the bus bar, and the dimensions of the panel.

Comment: Somebody needs to make an answer with 'dead face cover' in it. But I just wanted to note that it's beautifully wired. I'd be thrilled if all my jobs had electrical work like that.

Comment: Not sure how to add pictures.  I really appreciate y’all rapid response.  The tag on left indicates this “model”:   HOM20L125C

Comment: @TimP5  -- hit [edit] in the "share edit ..." on the bottom left of your post, and then you'll be able to use the "mountain and sun" button in the editor toolbar to add your pics

Comment: @threephaseeel - Thanks.  Added.

Comment: Your 2nd and last pics are the same. Did you accidentally post one twice, or was the last one supposed to be different?

Comment: Gotta admit, though, @Harper-ReinstateMonica Mr. Snippy produced the neatest set of ground wires I think _I've_ ever seen. (Inconvenient to rearrange anything, but... picturesque!)

Comment: @Freeman which is fine,because no reason to move a ground :)

Answer (score 4):

### Guess you'll have to go shopping for secondhand electrical parts

The good news is that with all the labeling in hand, it's rather easy to figure out which cover you need; the labels say right on them that this takes a HOMC20L125 cover.  However, your loadcenter is of an older design (Series 03) that has been discontinued for some time now, and according to [this Square-D FAQ](https://www.se.com/us/en/faqs/index?page=content&id=FA117170&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US), the HOMC20L125 cover is no longer available from Square-D, with no substitute parts provided.  So, you'll have to find either the cover itself or a complete HOM20L125C series 03 loadcenter (note that Series 01 and 02 use a different cover P/N, and so do the series S0x Homeline loadcenters as they have *convertible mains*, a feature your loadcenter likely lacks given the lack of height up top) that you can harvest the cover from.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to replacing the cover, it seems unlikely that the neutral bus bars allow two wires per screw (especially considering there are 40 screw spots in a 20-space panel, plus the added accessory ground bar). Permitting two (or more) ground wires per screw is common, more than one neutral wire (or mixing ground and neutral is not). The neutrals should likely be redistributed so that there is only one under each screw.

Comment: It's not just "seems unlikely" -- UL 67 has required 1 neutral to a hole for forever, and NEC 408.41 Codified that requirement back in the early 2000s